# add multi testng annotations

Tags: java, annotations, testng

```
@Test
@MyAnnotations({
@MyDefindeAnnotation(name="A"),
@MyDefindeAnnotation(name="B")
})
public void testMix(){}
```

I want to define an annotaion "MyAnnotations", that contains a list of annotation named ' MyDefindeAnnotation'. MyDefindeAnnotation can do something before run case and after case . I want to run testMix() multiple times, everytime with different MyDefindeAnnotaion。

Just like this：
first time: MyDefindeAnnotation-A do something  -> run testMix() ->  MyDefindeAnnotaion-A do something 
second time: MyDefindeAnnotation-B do something  -> run testMix() ->  MyDefindeAnnotaion-B do something 
If just add one annotation, I can use IInvokedMethodListener， override onStart() method or beforeInvocation() method. But I want to multiple Annotation, I don't know how to loop run case.

Comment: That feels like bad design since the tests would be temporarily coupled for example (What would running a _second_ time mean? What would be the difference between running the test once now and again in say 30 minutes?). What exactly are you trying to do? If the tests are different why not have 2 methods?

Comment: MyDefindeAnnotaion will call a server to do something. The server will do different thing according the value of MyDefindeAnnotaion. So the test case is same but the condition is different. I just want to reuse the cases for the different condition.

Comment: Ok so the server will react differently based on the values sent. What I still don't get is why you don't just have let's say `@MyDefindeAnnotation(name="A") void testA()` and `@MyDefindeAnnotation(name="B") void testB()`. If those 2 methods would have to share a lot of code then you could just move that into methods they're calling.